# different layout for print

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on asp.net MVC3 application and I have created a layout.cshtml which is used like master page. I want to create another layout template and use it for print ( media=print) Can I switch the layout when print preview is clicked ?

Comment: Should you not be asking this on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563772/print-friendly-asp-net-mvc-3-view/ - The question you asked yesterday?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use two stylesheets, one for printing (CSS media types):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

This stylesheet would selectively apply `display:none;` to the elements you don't want displayed in the printed version